# URL trailing slash gets removed

Tags: .htaccess, apache2.4, trailing-slash

I recently found a bug that when i go to `example.com/phpmyadmin` or `example.com/index` the trailing slash gets removed, so it's calling `example.comphpadmin` or `example.comindex`. This happens with everything after the slash. But if i have a second trailing slash like `example.com/index/home` it works perfectly.

I have a redirect from http to https active in my site config, running apache2.4.

My config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.net
    Redirect permanent / https://example.net
</VirtualHost>
```

And my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond $1 !^(phpmyadmin|index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I looked around but found no answers. Maybe there is something wrong with my config and somebody could help me.

Comment: Please don't deface your post by rolling back our improvements.

Comment: Alright, sorry, I'm new to this whole site and didn't exactly see what you did to it, i thought you deleted some of the text, but as i see you changed it to code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Considering that this RewriteRule doesn't even execute for /phpmyadmin due to the RewriteCond, and the RewritRule doesn't redirect, the problem is a bug in whoevers index.php you're sending all the unknown resources to.

Or, you've not shown us the actual configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I was being dumb and just had to clear the cache to get it working. I don't know what exactly wasn't working but my changes i made before making this post did work out, just the cache still had the faulty version in it.